# The assumptions regarding the t-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, assumptions, randomness

The t-test has an assumption that the sample provided has to be random in nature. Do we test our sample for randomness before carrying out the t-test ?

Comment: I do. BTW, there is no single $t$-test, there are different flavors of $t$-tests but unless normality can be assumed without fear of contradiction, a contradiction may arise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clarification on t-test assumptions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181711/clarification-on-t-test-assumptions)

Comment: @Carl how do you test for randomness?

Comment: @user2974951 [Shapiro-Wilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) testing is the most commonly used test for normality of a random variate. OP probably does not know how to ask the question properly with respect to the implied assumptions of $t$-testing. That did not stop me from answering, I knew what was meant. OP did not ask for the test name, only if `we` do a test, and `I` do.

Comment: @Carl Idon't get it, the Shapiro-Wilk test tests whether a sample comes from a normal distribution, not whether the observations in the sample are random? I believe that was the OP's question.

Comment: I think the OP is using randomness and independence synonymously when they aren't.  samples are generally random but the question to ask is whether the samples are independent. that is one assumption that the t-test uses. there are others but they vary depending on the specific t-test used and specific situation. but independence of observations is assumed no matter what the specifics.

Comment: @user2974951 Randomness is not always a uniform distribution, sometimes it is a normal distribution, sometimes a beta distribution, and so forth. What are you unsure of? I do lots of tests on my assumptions, not writing a book of comments here. Read https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/181711/99274 for assumptions here.

Comment: @Carl I am not talking about distributions, I am talking about random / independent observations of the sample as I believe that was the OP's question, not whether the sample comes from a normal distribution. I believe the OP is asking how to test whether the observations are drawn at random (for ex. checking correlation).

Comment: One doesn't test a sample for randomness: that determination (however broadly one might conceive of "randomness") is made by understanding how the sample was obtained or by making modeling assumptions.  "Randomness" and statistical *distribution* are completely different issues, making me concerned that the comments by @Carl may be misleading rather than clarifying.

Comment: @whuber Someone else (the OP) used a word out of context. The OP really wants to know what assumptions to test. I was challenged on the OPs use of the word. Well, it is not my word choice. I merely tried to understand the context which has been dealt with [elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/181721/99274).

Comment: @Carl If you seek to understand how the OP intends a word to mean, then *please ask.* If you direct them in a particular way and that turns out not to have been their intention, they will have been misled.

Comment: @whuber *Reductio ad absurdum*: The word "randomness" is out of context. There is only one correct context: 'some test or other'. Note: if the OP was aware of a particular specific test, the OP would have asked that. As the French say, (translated) *There are not 36 solutions.* It does nothing further to ask anyone anything, and do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Carl Asserting there is "only one correct context" belies a lack of imagination concerning the origin of the question. Regardless, if you think a word in a question is out of context or misused, then please *point that out* and then *ask for clarification.*  Do not presume that all readers will find only one way to interpret an ambiguous usage.

Comment: @whuber Too much imagination, perhaps. My mistake, I was trying to help the OP without being concerned if anyone else understands either the OP or my comment. The OP likely does not know exactly what "randomness' means in this context or the question would not have been classifiable as ambiguous by anyone, and no, it does not seem ambiguous to me. So, let's ask with a bit of prompting, "Apoorwa Srivastava, What do you mean by "randomness"? Did you mean "Some test or other to guarantee one has met the assumptions needed for assurance that the *t*-test  has been applied correctly?"

Comment: @Carl Agreed on all points -- and your questions at the end of that comment are spot-on.

Answer (score 3):

If by "random" you are referring to the sample being a random selection from the population, then it will depend on the field but, in the areas in which I work, there's often no test for randomness because there's no complete list of the population. So, we have to assume things, often unrealistically. This should be made clear when you write up results.